# I need to achieve following structure using flex

Tags: css, flexbox

[fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdwfw.png)

```html
<ul> <li>list1</li> <li>list2</li> <li>list3</li> </ul>
```

[Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRIX6.png)

lists have been arranged using flex. But I am getting structure as shown in fig 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on column direction and update item order and you can easily do this with flexbox:

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:200px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul >li {
  height:50%;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul >li:nth-child(2) {
  height:100%;
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list1</li>
  <li>list2</li>
  <li>list3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox doesn't support this type of grid. But you can do it using floats or using grids layout:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
     <li class="double">1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 50vh;
}
ul { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.double {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
li {
  border:2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxLLrL

Comment: `Flexbox doesn't support this type of grid` --> this is false, better remove it as we can do this with flex

Comment: Flexbox is made for one dimensional layouts and Grid is made for two dimensional layouts. If you want to obtain that layout you must use nested flexgrid.

Comment: what you said is wrong we can do this with flexbox : https://jsfiddle.net/6djrwkud/ .. you provided a grid solution so you can simply keep it and don't say "we cannot do it with flex"

Comment: i don't said you can't do with flexbox. But your is a good solution.

Comment: You clearly said `Flexbox doesn't support this type of grid` and when someone will read this he will think that there is no way to do it with flexbox.